# Changing textColor with @IBInspectable inside array of Labels

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, user-interface

I have weekDaysContainerView subclassing UIView, and trying to change textColor with @IBInspectable. Interface Builder show options to change color inside of it, but it never does in real app.

```
var weekdays = [UILabel]()

@IBInspectable var dayLabelColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray {
    didSet {
        for day in weekdays {
            day.textColor = dayLabelColor
        }
    }
}

lazy var dayLabelContainerView : UIView = {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    let view = UIView()

    for index in 1...7 {

        let day: NSString = formatter.weekdaySymbols[index % 7 ] as NSString
        let weekdayLabel = UILabel()

        weekdayLabel.text = day.substring(to: 3).uppercased()
        weekdayLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
        weekdayLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        view.addSubview(weekdayLabel)
        weekdays.append(weekdayLabel)
    }

    addSubview(view)

    return view
}()
```

Comment: Are you using `dayLabelContainerView` just in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`?

Comment: Add that subview in this func ?